Not updating list of open orders on MT5 API Python
I need to see the list of my open orders updated each minute.
Launching this code:
to_date = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Rome'))
from_date = to_date - timedelta(days = 1)
deals = mt5.history_orders_get(from_date, to_date, group=f"*{ticker}*")
df=pd.DataFrame(list(deals),columns=deals[0]._asdict().keys())
df['time_setup'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_setup'], unit='s')
df['time_done'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_done'], unit='s')

I see that the dataframe resulting considers only those positions closed on the previous day, and not also those on the current day.
dataframe not updated
Could you help me?
I tried changing the start date and to date, also modifying the timezones (utc) but the list does not update and remains qual to the one of the previous day

Have you tried to set to_date = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Rome')) + timedelta(days = 1) ?

The API history_orders_get is for getting orders that are in history. That means the orders that are closed.
You need to use orders_get to get pending orders.

You need to use the orders_get method. In the example below, all open orders on the XAUUSD asset are searched:
orders=mt5.orders_get(symbol="XAUUSD")
while(len(orders) != 0):
    orders=mt5.orders_get(symbol="XAUUSD")
    if orders is None:
        print("No orders on XAUUSD, error code={}".format(mt5.last_error()))
    else:
        print("Total orders on XAUUSD:",len(orders))
        # display all active orders
        for order in orders:
            print(order)

